# Mysql Select query returns one row two times

Tags: mysql

This is my query:

```
SELECT SUM(`sales_order_products`.`quantity`) AS total
      ,SUM(`sales_order`.`total`) AS price
FROM `sales_order` AS `so`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `sales_order_products` AS `p` ON `so`.`id` = `p`.`order_id`
WHERE leasing = 0
```

In `sales_order` table I have 9 records and in `sales_order_products`, 10 records.
This is because one of the orders has 2 product. The `total` result is OK but the `price` returns the total of the order with the 2 products twice. Like my `sales_order` table records are something like:

```
id  total
1   10
2   10
3   10
4   10
5   20
```

And my my `sales_order_products` table is something like:

```
id  order_id  quantity
1   1         1
2   2         1
3   3         1 
4   4         1
5   5         1
6   5         1
```

Why the `SUM()` return the 5th record two times ?
`LEFT OUTER JOIN` statement gets the results only from the left table, right? Which in my case is the `sales_order`. In my understanding it should return `total` column result like `60` and now it returns `80`. Where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: can you show the result of your query?

Comment: Are you not missing group by `sales_order`.`id`?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN statement does NOT get the results only from the left table.  It gets the result from the left table even if there is no match in the right table.  If there is a match, there will be one row for each match (as for inner join).  In order to only to only get the result from the left table use IN/EXISTS subqueries.

Comment: Which table has the column `leasing`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because there are two row in the `sales_order_products` table which is `order_id = 5`, the will relation with `sales_order` table, which `id = 5`

so there will be all match in the `JOIN`

In your case, you can use `DISTINCT` remove duplicate then `join`

```
CREATE TABLE sales_order(
   ID INT,
   total INT
);


INSERT INTO sales_order VALUES (1,10);
INSERT INTO sales_order VALUES (2,10);
INSERT INTO sales_order VALUES (3,10);
INSERT INTO sales_order VALUES (4,10);
INSERT INTO sales_order VALUES (5,20);

CREATE TABLE sales_order_products(
   ID INT,
   order_id INT,
  quantity INT
);


INSERT INTO sales_order_products VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO sales_order_products VALUES (2,2,1);
INSERT INTO sales_order_products VALUES (3,3,1); 
INSERT INTO sales_order_products VALUES (4,4,1);
INSERT INTO sales_order_products VALUES (5,5,1);
INSERT INTO sales_order_products VALUES (6,5,1);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
   SUM(`sales_order`.`total`) as total,
   SUM(sop.`quantity`) as total
FROM `sales_order`
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `quantity`,`order_id` FROM `sales_order_products`) sop
ON `sales_order`.`id` = sop.`order_id`
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07e6e8/11/0)**:

```
| total | total |
|-------|-------|
|    60 |     5 |
```

Comment: This query does not give independent sums for price and quantity like the original query.